# SSL-сертификат для бота

Tags: telegram-bot, домен, сертификат

Ситуация: есть сервер, public ip, но нету домена.

Я сделал самоподписанный сертификат, можно ли его использовать для запросов?

Насколько я нагуглил, сертификат типа `letsencrypt` нельзя установить, не имея домена.
Т. е. даже для использования самоподписного сертификата нужен домен?

Comment: Погугли домен первого уровня .tk

Comment: связанные вопросы [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2043617/4279) и [LetsEncrypt SSL on IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36303344/4279)